# Not getting the account association bonus

Tags: support, reputation, linked-accounts, association, association-bonus

Hello,

I have three SE accounts. SO, meta, and DYI (http://diy.stackexchange.com). I have had the meta account for about a week. I just got 203 rep on SO. I then signed up for DYI.

Both meta and DYI still have only 1 rep, I didn't get the 100 rep connection bonus on DYI for having 200+ rep on SO.

Upon reading other meta threads I found suggestions of going to the account tab and clicking "Clear All Associations" and logging off, then back on.  I have tried this twice, but still no rep bonus on either meta or DYI.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, it's fixed.  I am not sure if I did something wrong originally, or something else happened.

One thing that I did try that *may* have made a difference is that after I did the "Clear All Associations" and logged off, I logged back onto the DYI site **first**. I was then greeted with the bonus message.