# Account Association Bonus not Awarded

Tags: support, linked-accounts, association-bonus

I know this has been [discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56506/award-account-association-bonus-automatically-upon-reaching-200-rep) [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88009/not-getting-the-account-association-bonus), but I seem to be missing something. About a month ago, I crossed the 200 reputation barrier in my Code Review account. Because that account is associated with my Stack Overflow account, I should receive a +100 bonus in my Stack Overflow account, am I right?

I read in [old posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50508/no-bonus-points-on-linking-the-accounts) that people used to unassociate and then re-associate their accounts to trigger the +100 bonus, but this is not possible nowadays, as there's some automatic process that awards the bonus. If that's how things work, why haven't I received my bonus? I believe that the automatic process must have run already, I've been waiting for a whole month.

Comment: If you got that bonus for *every* account over 200, [that's over 1000 extra rep I'd have.  Everywhere](http://stackexchange.com/users/213609/john?tab=accounts).  Hmm, maybe we should do this....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope. You get a bonus on *all* account, present and future, when you cross 200 on a site for the *first* time.

You do *not* get extra bonuses for any accounts that cross 200 thereafter. Your SO account crossed 200 long ago, and you have gotten the bonus on all the sites you have accounts on (also on any site you create an account on).

Answer (score 2):

You already received the Association Bonus on your Stack Overflow account, clear back on October 3, 2011. You don't get an additional bonus for each account you get above 200 reputation.